# Create Function from selection from common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, common-table-expression

I need to create function from a complex query which was generating temp tables from the main table, to do subtraction in certain value based on condition. Temp tables are `setone`, `settwo`, `setthree`, and the main table is called `main`. The query is below.

```
with
    setone
    AS
        (SELECT type_id
              , time
              , id
              , type
           FROM main
          WHERE type = 0),
    settwo
    AS
        (SELECT type_id
              , time
              , id
              , type
           FROM main
          WHERE type = 1),
    setthree
    AS
        (SELECT setone.*
              , (SELECT max(time)
                   FROM settwo
                  WHERE settwo.id = setone.id
                    AND settwo.time < setone.time)
                    AS off
           FROM setone)
  SELECT id, SUM (off - time) / COUNT (*) MEAN
    FROM setthree
GROUP BY id
```

Now, The result from the query is value called MEAN, how to create function based on this query that pass `id` and `time` then will return value `MEAN`.
Function will look like
 `dbo.[FunctionGetMEAN](id,time) as MEAN`

Example of expected result:

```
id  time    mean
222   1     0.3
333   1     0.7
222   2     0.8
```

Comment: "Now I need to create function to pass the `MEAN` as parameter."  . . . I don't get it.

Comment: The result from the query is value called MEAN, now in order to create function based on this query that pass value MEAN, How it could be done. It is not direct selection @gordanlinoff.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to create a function with a parameter of @Mean?

Comment: At the end there, it looks like you are looking to divide the SUM of 'off' minus 'time' by the COUNT of records in either a table or table valued function 'mean'. Is this right?

Comment: If you delete the word MEAN out of it, it would give you the average difference between off and time in set three. By the way these are CTE's or Common Table Expressions rather than temp tables.

Comment: Even after reading all the comments, I'm still not sure what you mean by "pass" value MEAN.. For a function to work, you need to pass it something .. do something with it and get something in return.. what do you want to pass and what do you want to get in return? Can you provide sample data and expected results please?

Comment: Thanks for comment @Harry. I edit the post.

Comment: I just realised your whole cte is incorrect you should go; with data as ( select .... from... Where...  ) select * from data where...

Answer (score 0):

Ah. What you might want is a stored procedure. Look up create procedure . Basic syntax goes like this..

```
Create procedure dbo.procedurename 
( @id int 
, @time int) 

As 

Begin
```

- your query here*

Where statement needs to.be included before the group by

```
Where 

Id = @id 
And time = @time
```

The last statement needs to be :

```
End
```

You then call yiur stored procedure like this for example.

```
Exec dbo.yourprocedure 1, 100
```

Comment: Put a semicolon before with like this ;with

Comment: If you write what I have suggested then sql will return the group Id  and the corresponding mean. You don't need to return anything

Comment: You don't have to do that . Can you please post your stored procedure code and the error message

Comment: Ensure your ;with is followed by an opening bracket ( and close the bracket before you select from the cte.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, I noticed some wrong on result from query, anyway I tried bracket, did not wrok

Comment: @jou can you post your full query please